# Get a value from input to use in controller Angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, firebase

This sounds a really simple task that I've been struggling to do, here it goes..

I need to get the value of an input box that a user will type in their text to then pass the value to my controller in Angular JS. The value is passed to the controller upon button click, which I can then use this value in my code, i.e. simple console or alert to verify it's working.

However, I've tried various solutions which do not work. Please a code snippet below:

**HTML**

```
<label for="newEmail" class="sr-only">New email address</label>
<input data-ng-model="updateUser.newEmail" type="text" id="newEmail"
maxlength="254" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" size="20"
class="form-control" placeholder="{{user.email}}">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" 
data-ng-click="updateUser.updateProfile()" style="margin: 
3px">Update</button>
```

**JS**

```
app.controller('adminCtrl', ['$scope', 'Auth', '$state', '$firebaseArray', 
'$timeout', '$firebaseArray', function($scope, Auth, $state, $firebaseArray, 
$timeout) {

$scope.updateUser = {
    email: ''
};

$scope.updateProfile = function () {
    console.log('User clicked register', $scope.updateUser.email);
};

}]);
```

Please note I'm using various dependencies in the controller that are for further functionality that all works perfectley. The main issue above I've tried (and various others) either return a blank value or the message 'undefined'.

Thanks,

Comment: Your `ngModel` bind with `updateUser.newEmail` where as your print value in console is `$scope.updateUser.email`. So please change ether in `ngModel` from `newEmail` to `email` or change in `console` from `$scope.updateUser.email` to `updateUser.newEmail`.

Comment: I've just tried changing the console to just updateUser.newEmail and also tried changing the object from: '$scope.updateUser = {
    email: ''
};' to '$scope.updateUser = {
    newEmail: ''
};'. Neither option works and nothing is displayed in the console at all when I click the 'Update button.

Comment: I've tried many of the options here and I probably haven't helped myself by not stating that I'm using ng-repeat here to populate a table with rows and that is where the input box is held. I assume this might be to do with the problem???

Comment: if you discribe all your logic in plnkr then its benificial for us to find the exact issue.

Comment: I think I will do that, although I've fixed the problem now but also have another issue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be having a number of different issues with your code.

1. In your controller definition you have specified `$firebaseArray` twice.
2. What variables do you want to expose on your controller? Currently you are exposing `updateUser` which is an object with a single property *and* you are exposing a function called `updateProfile`.
3. In your html your accessing `updateUser.updateProfile()` which clearly will not work. `updateProfile` lives directly under scope with your current code.

Comment: This finally work, thank you! Although, I've got another slight problem now. I will post up the code in Plunker if you could help out :)

Comment: It might take me a bit of time to post it up there and it's also for a client who has a Firebase database that I can't expose. The problem I'm now getting is that I've got a placeholder in the specific table cell that takes in the value from a further input box that sends a value to Firebase. When I change the value in the input box it now also seems to change the placeholder in the other rows...???

Comment: Sounds like you have the same model bound to *all* rows

Comment: That's right, although I need the bound to be specific for that row that I'm finding difficult. Can't seem to use $id or $index before perhaps so it only displays the bound

Comment: Well it sounds like you're using some kind of `ng-repeat`. Looping through a collection should be fine, without mixing your models. Also using `$index` shouldnt conflict, it simply gives you the index of the specific row.

Comment: I'm using ng-repeat in a table and for some reason I can't increment the bounds so to speak, so they are individual for that row only. Is there any workaround or example you could provide?

Comment: So you actually *want* to access items across the rows?

Comment: That's right, but I simply want to use the bound method for that row rather than on all rows

Answer (score 0):

> Attribute `pattern` is causing issue here. Remove `pattern` and it will work.

Unless provided value does not match the pattern, model value is not updated.

`updateUser.newEmail` is not defined anywhere. If you are accessing `updateUser.email`, your model name should match with that..

`updateUser"` object does not have method `updateProfile()"`, it should be accessed directly.

Try this:

```js
var saApp = angular.module("saApp", []);
saApp.controller('numberController', function($scope) {
  $scope.updateUser = {
    email: ''
  };
  $scope.updateProfile = function() {
    console.log('User clicked register', $scope.updateUser.email);
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="saApp" ng-controller="numberController">
  <label for="newEmail" class="sr-only">New email address</label>
  <input ng-model="updateUser.email" type="text" id="newEmail" maxlength="254" size="20" class="form-control"> 
  {{updateUser.email}}
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" ng-click="updateProfile()" style="margin: 
3px">Update</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This works on here and I've tried the code in my version, yet I think the ng-repeat issue described above might be causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

is the input you want to get the value the one with id newEmail?
then you just have to make sure you have the right ng-model which is updateUser.newEmail

try this:
console.log('User clicked register', $scope.updateUser.newEmail);